# How do I write a SQL select statement using regular expressions that will display the two words in LEFT in reverse order

Tags: sql, regex, oracle-sqldeveloper, computer-science

For example I'm have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR
(
    LEFT VARCHAR(50),
    RIGHT VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Then insert some values to table CAR:

```
INSERT INTO CAR (LEFT, RIGHT)
VALUES ('super car', 'car super')
```

Now I want to write a select statement by using regexp_replace (which I'm really unfamiliar with) to display the two words in LEFT column in reverse order and in two separate output column. I will appreciate any suggestion! Thank you!

The output should be looked like this:

```
column1   column2
-------------------
car       super
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `regexp_substr` function to split your string.

```
select regexp_substr('super car', '([[:space:]].*)', 1, 1), regexp_substr('super car', '(.*?)([[:space:]])', 1, 1) from dual
```

using `regexp_replace` function.

```
select regexp_replace('super car','(.*?)([[:space:]])'), regexp_replace('super car', '([[:space:]].*)') from dual
```

Comment: Can I use regexp_replace to do that? I want to know more about it.

Comment: Allright thank you sir I think I should read more on the Oracle website, I'm really confused because of the symbols.

Answer (score 2):

`CREATE TABLE car (
    left    VARCHAR(50),
    right   VARCHAR(50)
)`


`insert into CAR(LEFT,RIGHT)
values('super car', 'car super');`

`select regexp_replace(left,'(.*?)([[:space:]])') AS COLUMN1,regexp_replace(left, '([[:space:]].*)') AS COLUMN2 from CAR;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir and it's work, BTW do you know the correct way to assign column aliases to this select statement?

Comment: in the above select statement I have used using column1 and column2 aliases. different ways you can use aliases in SQL. Check the this link

https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-alias/